# How to get a notification when the device is out of the path in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

How to notify when the device is going in the wrong direction in Android GPS programatically. I have a path set default.I have set the path like this :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ 12.756742 + "," + 76.67523465 + "&daddr=" + 12.64345213 + "," + 76.875432));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);`
```

While moving from one point to another the device should move only to that path. When the user moves out of that path (say + or - 100 meters towards right or left) it should notify user.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried making a component to check the GPS at a interval?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this link could help you

"http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double, double, float, long, android.app.PendingIntent)"

Paste it in address without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Create Notifcation
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Cancel the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    //

    // Specify the called Activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ur_activity.class);

    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "your tittle",
            "ur notifi text", activity);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

And use this in onLocationChanged(); there u can handle when you are in a good way or not.(there u can check the latitude and longitude.)